# Regarding Google Safe Browsing API

Tags: php, javascript, firefox

Does anyone know how to use the Google safe browsing API.

I downloaded the entire the malware and phish update from the google safe browsing using the API key and tried comparing the hash of the suspicious site (md5_file method in php) but it did not work. I also tried comparing the hash of the suspicious site's url (md5 method in php).

Am I doing something  wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you can specify more exactly what you are doing? The URL you hash must be Suffix/Prefix only, no protocol etc. included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a canonical version of the site url.  The canonicalization algorithm is officially documented, along with examples, at https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/urls-hashing#canonicalization .  Also, I think using the suffix or prefix of the url may be necessary depending on what you are doing with the url.

Answer (score -2):

Also, check out the [BrightCloud web filtering API](http://bcws.brightcloud.com).  It's a bit more straightforward to use (a REST web interface).  It's better, but does cost money (it's still quite affordable).

(FWIW - I am a founder of BrightCloud.)

Comment: Great service, buy very expensive if you have to pay 100$ just for try the API!